# Advent 4211 netbook - only 4 keys working

Tags: laptop, keyboard, netbook

The keys are: caps lock, a, backslash & z.

I opened the netbook earlier to clean the dust out of the fan. Is there someway I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard ribbon cable that goes to the motherboard probably just needs to be re-seated.
Re-open it, track where the keyboard connects to the motherboard. Undo the socket, typically by flipping open a latch, remove and then re-insert the cable. Verify that you haven't previously torn the keyboard ribbon cable.

Comment: A lot of these nowadays don't even have the latch, so it's easy for them to pop loose without noticing.